# DMARC test failed but we didn't find any obvious reason why; DMARC not passing while SPF and DKIM do

Tags: email, dmarc, opendmarc

About 7 days ago, I found out on https://www.mail-tester.com that *sometimes* (50% of my tries over a couple of days) my company email does not pass [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) test. As it states it does not *know why*, I am helpless right now and don't really understand what is happening.

I get this message:

> The DMARC test failed but we didn't find any obvious reason why.
>   If you recently modified your DNS, please wait a few hours and then test again.
>
> DMARC DNS entry found for the domain **_dmarc.vlastimilburian.cz**:
>
> ```
> "v=DMARC1; p=reject; adkim=s; aspf=s"
> ```
>
> Verification details:

- > ```
  > mail-tester.com; dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=vlastimilburian.cz header.i=@vlastimilburian.cz header.b=CefZgBpZ; dkim-atps=neutral
  > ```
- > ```
  > mail-tester.com; dmarc=none header.from=vlastimilburian.cz
  > ```
- > ```
  > mail-tester.com; dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=vlastimilburian.cz header.i=@vlastimilburian.cz header.b=CefZgBpZ; dkim-atps=neutral
  > ```
- > ```
  > From Domain: vlastimilburian.cz
  > ```
- > ```
  > DKIM Domain: vlastimilburian.cz
  > ```

---

I have a **[ProtonMail premium plan](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/paid-plans/)** with one custom domain and a single email address. My domain DNS is protected with **[DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions)**.

I have DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)) also.

My SPF record is a hard-fail:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx -all
```

Strange thing is, both [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), and [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) are passing:

[image: DMARC not passing while SPF and DKIM do]

---

I did not modify my DNS in 3 days, is there any other possible reason for [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) to fail?

---

### Update 2019-May-27

I got a reply from the [Mail-Tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com)'s staff:

> Thank you for sharing this link. I'm afraid I quite still don't understand the answer over there... Basically, it says everything is OK and DMARC should pass... isn't it? If so, I'm afraid it does not help much... we use the famous **[OpenDMARC](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/)** library to analyze DMARC and the "we didn't find any obvious reason why" is generated when **[OpenDMARC](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/)** says your email does not pass DMARC while our own test does not find anything wrong.

---

Could this possibly be an error in [OpenDMARC](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/), should I report it?

---

I tried the test now, and it passed.

---

Additionally, I sent a message to my Gmail free-mail with PASS results:

[image: gmail test]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can read from the results:

- SPF verification passes, and the domain used in envelope sender matches the `From` header.
- DKIM verification passes with a matching `d=`.

This means you have a passing DMARC alignment from both, while only one is required. Based on that we can blame `mail-tester.com` for analysing it incorrectly.

Comment: Looks like a temporary error. Anything else would be speculation, as we don't have access to the source code of `mail-tester.com`.

Answer (score 0):

After I added an SPF record for the HELO server name (which is different from my domain name because of reverse DNS), my emails started passing this test at mail-tester.com.

See also [How do I prevent the SPF_HELO_NONE warning when sending from Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1064046/how-do-i-prevent-the-spf-helo-none-warning-when-sending-from-postfix)